# Mobile Phone Dialling - Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, call-manager

We have an Amazon Connect call centre we're setting up. Currently, we can make outbound calls and re-direct calls to agents on phone numbers ONLY for landlines, it won't recognise/call mobile numbers.

Is this a free tier limitation (dev environment) or something we have configured wrong? How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: AWS support is excellent. I suggest you're going to need support sooner or later, you might as well get it sooner and get the benefits, saving yourself time and money.

Answer (score 1):

Which country? We had to raise a support request to enable calling to some non-default countries. Now it works for mobiles just fine.

You can do it through the "Service Limit Increase" support request which doesn't require a support plan.

Comment: UK - now that's a good point, I think I've got it set up in a non-UK data centre at the moment. Thanks.